# JDE WCF service

Tags: wcf, jde

Is there a simple way in which I can create a JDE Provider BSSV service in a WCF service?  My requirement is that we need a third party which runs on a Microsoft platform.  An entry in the third party needs to consume the JDE web service to create record in the JDE and process the same in JDE and send back the data to third party. The Client requires only WCF web service.

Is there a way to create a JDE web service and host it as a WCF service?

Has anyone implemented such WCF service in the past?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, but it *sounds* like you have a client using WCF that wants to communicate with this JDE Web service.  WCF clients can communicate with non-WCF services, just like WCF services can have non-WCF clients.  That's the whole point of web services - platform agnosticism.

Answer (score 0):

Can we create a WCF service using JDeveloper on JDE. Do you have any advance document which can demonstrate the step by step process to follow. I have referred to some document on Oracle KT(Doc ID 1340777.1) but it does not help mcuh

Answer (score 0):

This document shows what you need to do in JDeveloper: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/jde-bssv-database-business-service-131800.pdf