# JD Edwards WCF Service

Tags: wcf, service, jde

Has anyone ever implemented a WCF Service using Jdeveloper on JD edwards.Can anyone help me with the step by step process so i can Implement the same.
I have a requirement where my client needs a WCF Service to be exposed so they can invoke and communicate to JDE and make entries to JDE DB.

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

duplicate of [JDE WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23738455/jde-wcf-service)

did you check the documentation that I had linked? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/jde-bssv-database-business-service-131800.pdf